# Closest location in R

Tags: r, memory, location

Hopefully someone has tackled something similar before - looking for some advice!

I have a dataset of 7 million customers and 900 locations, and I want to find each customers' closest location

In a database SQL this would be easy but I'm finding R to be tricky due to table sizes!

My standard SQL logic would be to cross join the two tables and find the minimum distance using abs() and Pythagoras, then find each customers closest store from that. Not the most efficient but it works.

However in R on my desktop (64 bit Windows, 8GB RAM) the data set is just too big to cross join!
I've tried looping using the below, which works...

```
now <- Sys.time()

for(i in 1:nrow(customers)) {
between <- Sys.time()

  distance <- distm(x=stores[,. (longitude,latitude)],y=customers[i,.(longitude,latitude)])

 customers_closest_temp <- data.table(cust_id=customers[i]$cust_id,                                            
location_code=stores[which(distance==min(distance))]$location_code,
                                  distance=min(distance))

   customers_closest <- rbind(customers_closest,customers_closest_temp)

  print(paste0("Iteration: ",i,", ",round(difftime(Sys.time(),between,units="secs"),3)," seconds, duration: ",round(difftime(Sys.time(),now,units="secs"))," seconds"))

 }
```

....But it's taking 0.2 seconds per customer, meaning it will take 16 days to run(!) 
I presume because it's slowly appending one row at a time?
I've also attempted trying to limit my cross join...

```
x<-unique(merge(customers, stores, by="key")[(((SQRT(((abs(x.longitude - y.longitude)) * (abs(x.longitude - y.longitude))) 
+ ((abs(x.latitude - y.latitude)) * (abs(x.latitude - y.latitude)))))/1000)) <= 10])
```

But no luck? (Think I'm doing this wrong)
Any help would be very much appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example "stores" and "customers" data and the expected output?

Comment: I actually posted the same question on reddit last night and got a working response, here it is for anyone else who is stuck!

https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/3r8ldo/finding_a_customers_closest_location_r_efficiency/